# Finding the rotation matrix $R$ in a product $A = R B R^{-1}$, knowing $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, classical-mechanics

I came across this problem from questions of classical mechanics and rotation of rigid bodies.

Given a diagonal matrix *A* (principal moments of inertia of a rigid object in a local reference frame) and an orthonomal matrix *R* (matrix to rotate the object's reference frame onto a general reference), I can derive a symmetric matrix *B* (moments of inertia in the general reference frame) though the relationship

$  B = R A R^{-1} $

Playing around with this, I can easily derive *A* from *B*, knowing *R*. The question that puzzled me is: could I also obtain the rotation matrix *R* if I know *A* and *B*? If so, which formulas would allow me to do so? Would I perhaps need additional information and which?

Comment: Well, it is not unique, if $R$ works, so does $-R$.

Comment: @copper.hat Only one of those is a proper rotation, though.

Comment: @eyeballfrog in what sense is $-R$ not a "proper rotation"?

Comment: For the distinction between proper and improper rotations please see section 3.3 of this journal paper https://www-jstor-org.tudelft.idm.oclc.org/stable/2027367 This is Arthur Mayer, Rotations and their algebra, SIAM Review, 1960, 2(2):77-122. Proper rotations are those transforming a right-handed coordinate systems into a right-handed one; improper those transforming a right-handed one into a left-handed one. The former have determinant +1, the latter -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is *similar* to $B$ due to the relation $B=RAR^{-1}$ for an invertible matrix $R$ (we don't even need orthogonality), we know that these matrices will have the same eigenvalues. But the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are just its diagonal entries (since $Ae_1=a_{1,1}e_1$ if $e_1$ is the first basis vector in the reference frame you're in). So, to get $R$ you will need to solve, column by column, for the eigenvectors $v_i$ of $B$ by calculating a non-zero vector that fulfils $(B-a_{i,i}\mathrm{\mathop{Id}})v_i=0$ (here, $\mathrm{\mathop{Id}}$ denotes the identity matrix of the same size as $B$).

When you've done that for all $i$, you will have ended up with the columns of your matrix, except $v_i$ still needs to be re-scaled. So the columns of your matrix $R_{-i}$ are equal to $\frac{v_i}{\|v_i\|}$:

$$R=\left(\frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|},\dotsc,\frac{v_d}{\|v_d\|}\right).$$

EDIT: If you want a proper rotation, you'll want to have $\det(R)=1$, but all we know is that $\det(R)=\pm1$. So, if you calculate your eigenvectors and the determinant ends up being negative, simply switch the sign of one of the columns $R_{-i}$.

Comment: Thanks for bringing the reasoning back to the origin of matrix $A$ as container of the eigenvalues of $B$ -- this is indeed where principal moments of inertia came from in the first place. Computationally, in Matlab/Octave the function `eig(B)` can return both $A$ and $R$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is diagonal, then $BR = RA$ shows that the columns of $R$ are eigenvectors of $B$ corresponding to $[A]_{kk}$. All that remains is scaling.